# Node.js routes authentication

Tags: node.js, authentication, jwt

I am quite new to node.js and I am trying to follow a tutorial, and trying to modify the structure of the project. On the tutorial, they have all the endpoints on the server.js file. I have created a folder for models, routes, and controllers. I am using JWT wet tokens.

On the tutorial they have the following code:

```
var authenticate = (req,res,next) => {
   var token = req.header('x-auth);

   User.findByToken(token).then((user) => {
     if(!user){
     return Promise.reject();
   }

   req.user = user;
   req.token = token;
   }).catch((e) => {
      res.status(401).send();
   });
  };

app.get ('users/me/', authenticate, (req,res) => {
   res.send(req.user);
});
```

I have created the following folder structure:
[image]

Here is my authenticate.js code:
[image]

Here is my UserModel.js code:
[image]

Here is my UserRoute.js code:
[image]

Here is my UserController.js code:
[image]

I have no idea how to use how to use my authenticate function inside my controller on export.get_user  (in red).

What I need to do or change?

Answer (score 0):

I will recommend you to read this nice article about [Express Middleware](http://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-middleware.html). Meanwhile you can solve the problem by passing `authenticate` like below.

**UserController.js**

```
// other code  

exports.get_user = function(req, res) {
   res.send(req.user);
}
```

**UserRoute.js**

```
module.exports = function(app) {
    // other code

    app.route('/user/me').get(authenticate, user.get_user);
}
```

Comment: I have tried this before but I am getting this error:

Comment: TypeError: Cannot read property 'findByToken' of undefined
    at authenticate (C:\Users\rolan\Documents\bookngo\middleware\authenticate.js:6:7)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\rolan\Documents\bookngo\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at next (C:\Users\rolan\Documents\bookngo\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:137:13)
    at Route.dispatch (C:\Users\rolan\Documents\bookngo\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:112:3)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\rolan\Documents\bookngo\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)

Comment: This is different error. Seems like you are not able to refer `User` in `authenticate`.